# Possible to add to to the "Additional Column Settings" for a Column in a list?

Tags: 2010, web-part

Is there any way that I can add an additional check box to the "Additional Column Settings" section of a Column in a list? I'm talking about the section pictured below:

[image]

I don't even know where to start looking for how I would do something like this, so any tutorials, links, or terms I should search on would be greatly appreciated.  Once I have this extra check box I would like to change the functionality of this text box based on the selection...

Comment: Could you please share your solution with me. I'm trying to do somewhat exactly the same thing. I need to put a checkbox called Enforce Unique Value For People Picker. Basically my form will have multiple number of People Picker. When user check this, it will check other People Picker control on the form that also have this attribute checked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As posted in your other post [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14377/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-new-column-type), you would have to create a new field type. In your case, I think you will want to work with the class [SPFieldText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldtext.aspx).

Comment: I have figured out how to add my own, but I still don't see how I can add to the "Additional Column Settings".  Do you know somewhere I could look to find that?

Comment: Not that I know of. Could you perhaps share what it is you are trying to achieve and someone could lead you down that road?

Comment: Nevermind, I found how to do that here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543558.aspx