# Is there a way to create a new Column type?

Tags: 2010, site-column

Is it possible to create a new Column Type in SharePoint? I did a little looking around but didn't find anything...  Below is an image that I hope clarifies what I am talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, it is possible. In technical terms, you need to create a new field type. Check the article below in SharePoint SDK to get started.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862248.aspx

Comment: Very useful link. thx

Comment: I think this article is well worth reading http://sharepointmagazine.net/articles/customizing-the-user-experience-of-sharepoint-custom-fields-deep-dive-part-5-of-6

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has already been answered but here is another article that may help  if you are using WSS 3/MOSS 2007 from MSDN Magazine (May 2009):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd727508.aspx